# Setting property values dynamically

Tags: c#, properties

I am using a PivotGrid(DevExpress).  I want to set AppearancePrint property settings in a for loop.

How do i use the variable type for properties such as Cell in the example below?

so instead of

```
grid.AppearancePrint.Cell.BackColor = Color.White;
grid.AppearancePrint.Cell.BackColor2 = Color.LightBlue;
```

I want to do this:

```
//datarow example <PrintAppearance Type="Cell" Font="Tahoma,8,Regular" BackColor="White" BackColor2="Light Grey"/>

foreach (DataRow dr in appearances)          
{
   string type = dr["Type"].ToString();
   grid.AppearancePrint.[type].BackColor = Color.FromName(dr["BackColor"].ToString());
   grid.AppearancePrint.[type].BackColor2 = Color.FromName(dr["BackColor2"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a form of script-parsing, and you'll need to use reflection in order to do it. For example:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in appearances) {
   string type = dr["Type"].ToString();

   PropertyInfo propertyForType = grid.AppearancePrint.GetType().GetProperty(type);
   object objectForProperty = propertyForType.GetValue(grid.AppearancePrint, null);

   PropertyInfo propertyForBackColor = objectForProperty.GetType().GetProperty("BackColor");
   PropertyInfo propertyForBackColor2 = objectForProperty.GetType().GetProperty("BackColor2");

   propertyForBackColor.SetValue(objectForProperty, Color.FromName(dr["BackColor"].ToString()), null);
   propertyForBackColor2.SetValue(objectForProperty, Color.FromName(dr["BackColor2"].ToString()), null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your exact problem but at a glance, it seems you'll need to use reflection as you won't know the type until runtime - In case you're not familiar with reflection, it will allow you to examine the object (and more importantly the properties on it)

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/net-reflection-set-object-property) for a possible solution

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I do intend to try this
Type type = target.GetType(); 
PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("propertyName"); 
prop.SetValue (target, propertyValue, null); 


Meanwhile, I found another way to do this without using reflection
            
DevExpress.Utils.AppearanceObject ao = grid.AppearancePrint.GetAppearance(type);

ao.Options.UseFont = true;
ao.BackColor = Color.FromName(dr["BackColor"].ToString());

Regards
HS