# Assign property of object by variable in C#.net

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.Net - Reflection set object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/net-reflection-set-object-property)

Is there any way I can achieve the following in C#.net?

```
$property = "name";
$myObject->$property = "Bob";
```