# Unable to perform variable interpolation in C# to find the object fields

Tags: c#, interpolation

I  am getting the user email id using below code in a MS Graph Api code:

```
user.Mail.Contains("John")
```

and also user DisplayName check  using:

```
user.DisplayName.Contains("John")
```

I want Mail and DisplayName to be defined based on specific conditions and store it in a variable.

i.e

```
if(somecondition){
  searchCriteria="Mail";
}

else{
searchCriteria="DisplayName";
}
```

and then using interpolation:

user.${searchCriteria}.Contains("John")

But ,it doesn't work in this case.

Please Help.

Comment: You would need to use reflection to do this.

Comment: Interpolation can only be used to create a string.  It can't be used to get object properties like this.

Comment: That's not string interpolation. That's sort of a dynamic property. Are you a PHP programmer?

Comment: @ThomasWeller No , i am using C# code.

Comment: @JonathonChase I checked this link, but not getting any help . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292078/refer-to-a-property-name-by-variable