# ASP.NET, C#, How to dynamically identify the properties or method of a user control and add value to them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, user-controls, code-behind

In want to add dynamically the properties or methods of a user control from the code behind like this:

```
foreach (DataRow drModuleSettings in dsModuleSettings.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dsModuleSettings.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SettingValue"].ToString()))
        userControl.Title = dsModuleSettings.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SettingValue"].ToString();
}
```

The "userControl.Title" is a sample, in fact it should be replaced by such a code:

```
        userControl.drModuleSettings["SettingName"] = dsModuleSettings.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SettingValue"].ToString();
```

The problem is I don't know how to do this.

Please someone help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking to set unknown properties at runtime?

Comment: The properties are not unknown. They are saved in database and presented in dsModuleSettings.

Comment: How do you know if the control has those properties?

Comment: They are predefined in another table and user is just able to set the values of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use **Reflection**.

Have a look at the following code and references:

See here: [Set object property using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/net-reflection-set-object-property)

Also, here: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/19232-Set-Property-value-dynamically-using-Reflection.aspx:

This code is from the above reference:

```
// will load the assembly
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\MyClassLibrary.dll");

// get the class. Always give fully qualified name.
Type ReflectionObject = myAssembly.GetType("MyClassLibrary.ReflectionClass");

// create an instance of the class
object classObject = Activator.CreateInstance(ReflectionObject);

// set the property of Age to 10. last parameter null is for index. If you want to send any value for collection type
// then you can specify the index here. Here we are not using the collection. So we pass it as null
ReflectionObject.GetProperty("Age").SetValue(classObject, 10,null);

// get the value from the property Age which we set it in our previous example
object age = ReflectionObject.GetProperty("Age").GetValue(classObject,null);

// write the age.
Console.WriteLine(age.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I got my answer from the reference you suggested (http://stackoverflow.com/a/619788/2067991)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dynamic` properties. Which would mean that, `userControl.drModuleSettings` will be of type `dynamic`.

You can then assign it a value at runtime like

```
userControl.drModuleSettings = new {SomeProperty = "foo", AnotherProperty = "bar"};
```

More about dynamic keyword and DynamicObject [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx).

Note - Requires C# 4.0 or above.

Comment: unfortunately I use C# 3.5. Any alternative for this?

Comment: Then I guess reflection is your friend, and glad you've found your answer using just that :)