# Object to Object Mapping

Tags: c#, json

I have a RESTful service which returns JSON that I am deserialising into classes in c#.
I need to map some of the properties from the deserialised object model into properties in a different class.

However, I would like to do this through an (xml?) config file which can specify the from/to property names, so that mappings can be changed without recompiling code.

For example:

`objectA.Name.FirstName = objectB.FirstName`

`objectA.Name.LastName = objectB.LastName`

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Post something that _works_ and then ask if it can be _better_.

Answer (score 1):

You could let something like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) do the mapping for you.

There are [samples](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/tree/develop/src/AutoMapperSamples) in the source code and configuration options in the [wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki).

Comment: If you are not too worried about performance AutoMapper will work just fine, otherwise manual mapping is the moest performant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to to be based on late binding you can use reflection to dynamically execute the property assignments based on xml definitions.

You can see some examples in this asnwer: [Set object property using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection)