# Dynamic type - reference attribute with string parameter

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection

given global is of type dynamic:

```
public void addGuiMethodHandler(string methodName, Handler handler)
{
    using (global)
    {
        global.methodName = handler;
    }
}
```

But in the runtime "methodName" is referenced instead of it's value (from method arg).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably need to add more code - and to me it's totally unclear what problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to set a property on a class based upon a string, you'll need to use reflection. See [Set object property using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection)

The type of global doesn't matter (except in whether the attempt will be successful).