# How to assign values to a property whose name is in a string?

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to assign value to the property of the object of class. I have taken the list of property names using `GetProperties();`

```
      PropertyInfo [] props;
      props=typeof(Import_Column).GetProperties();
```

I have created an object

```
      Import_Column myobj=new Import_Column();
```

I want to do something like

```
      myobj.props[2]=value; //giving me error
```

*How can i do it? is there any different approach?*

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the value to the property of the current object instance

```
string propertyName = "TheNameOfThePropertyToSet";
myobj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(myobj, value, null);
```

or in your case you could use

```
myobj.GetType().GetProperty(props[2].Name).SetValue(myobj, value, null);
```