# ASP NET: Is it possible to set control property dynamically?

Tags: asp.net

On my aspx page has a button. I want to change its property dynamically.

For example:
A button which ID is Button1 and I want to change its property Visible to false.
On code behind have three variables `hidefield = "Button1"`, `property = "Visible"` and `value = false`.
Is it possible to set the property Visible using the variables?

aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" />
```

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hidefield = "Button1";
    string property = "Visible";
    bool value = false;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Control myControl1 = FindControl(hidefield);
        if (myControl1 != null)
        {
            myControl1.property = value; // <- I know this statement has error. Is there any way to set the property like this?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to use "property" as a variable. Also keep in mind `FindControl` isn't recursive, if you button is in  another control it won't be found.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection, based on [Set object property using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection)

```
using System.Reflection;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hidefield = "Button1";
    string property = "Visible";
    bool value = false;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Control myControl1 = FindControl(hidefield);
        if (myControl1 != null)
        {
            myControl.GetType().InvokeMember(hidefield ,
               BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
               Type.DefaultBinder, myControl, value);
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty messy and not very human readable so therefore could have maintainablility issues.

Comment: I can find the answer from your reference post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hidefield = "Button1";
    string property = "Visible";
    bool value = false;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       /* Use below two lines if you are using Master Page else you wouldnot be able to access your control */

        ContentPlaceHolder MainContent = Page.Master.FindControl("MainContent") as ContentPlaceHolder;
        Control myControl1 = MainContent.FindControl(hidefield);

        if (myControl1 != null)
        {
             myControl1.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(myControl1,value,null);  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
Button myControl1 = FindControl(hidefield) as Button;

 if (myControl1 != null)
 {
    myControl1.Visible= value; 
 }
```