# RavenDB - Update a single property to db when the property passed to a save-method could be any

Tags: c#, ravendb

I know a can save a single property to my db when knowing which propery I need to update, like this (the method `SaveContent` triggers trough a AJAX-post from the view):

```
public void SaveContent(string contentToUpdate)
{
    var page = Session.Load<CorePage>("CorePages/1");

    page.Title = contentToUpdate;
    RavenSession.SaveChanges();
}
```

But my problem is: the `(string contentToUpdate)`-parameter passed into my Save-method could be any property-value from my views @model-class because I use a WYSIWYG-editor om many places in the same view which means I never know which property that is passed in as `string contentToUpdate`. So I can't use the type of code a showed in my first exmple.

The `string contentToUpdate` could be any of these below:

```
public class CorePage
{
    public string WelcomeHeader { get; set; }
    public string WelcomeText { get; set; }
    public string LongText { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
}
```

So: How can I update a single-Property in var `page = Session.Load<CorePage>("CorePages/1");` when the `string contentToUpdate`-parameter could be any? And which other parameters do a probably need to pass into the save-method to solve this (the propertyName)?

EDIT:

I don't need to create a new property, I need to find witch property to set the value to.
So by passing in the propertyName as a parameter to my save-method I need to use that value(witch could be any of my properties in my class `CorePage`) to update that matching property.
Basiclly, I never know witch of my properties from `public class CorePage` is being sent to `public void SaveContent`

Take a look at this below, and you propably know what I mean:

```
 public void SaveContent(string propertyName, string contentToUpdate)
 {
     //Philip Kendalls method used here
     SaveContent(page => page.propertyName, contentToUpdate);
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set object property using reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection) as none of this is specific to RavenDB in any way; it's just about setting a property on an object.

Comment: Your web application needs to submit the name of the changed property. This has nothing to do with RavenDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you want to update one of the four properties `WelcomeHeader`, `WelcomeText`, `LongText` or `ShortDescription`. You can do this with a little use of [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397951.aspx):

```
public void SaveContent(Expression<Func<CorePage, string>> propertyToSet, string contentToUpdate)
{
    var page = Session.Load<CorePage>("CorePages/1");
    var memberExpression = (MemberExpression) propertyToSet.Body;
    var property = (PropertyInfo) memberExpression.Member;
    property.SetValue(page, contentToSet);
    RavenSession.SaveChanges();
}
```

and then call this something like `SaveContent(page => page.WelcomeHeader, "Welcome along!")`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very helpful. But I also need to set the propertyName dynamiclly. Please look at my EDIT and I show you what I mean.

Comment: In that case, you just want [simple reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/619788/525010) and this is a duplicate of that question as it's nothing to do with RavenDB.

Comment: As I formulated my question first, your solution answers that! And for my EDIT-part, the reference to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection/619788#619788) was also very helpful.