# c# Call class Member (property,method,etc) by dymanic name from Other class and method

Tags: c#, class, reflection, call

How can i call and then use (set value) for member of the class, when i do not know class name?

For best understanding let me show example, what i mean:

for example i have class:

```
static class ClassA {
    public static string Property1;
    public static bool Property2;
    public static async Task<bool> Method () {
     // ... 
     await Worker.Do();
     return true;
    } 
}

static class Worked {
   public static async Task<bool> Do() {
     // ... 
     var CallerClassName = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().ReflectedType.Name;

     // setup value for caller class Property 1 = "test";
     // Like ClassA.Property1 = "test"; but using dynamic name;
     // setup value for caller class Property 2 = true;
     // Like ClassA.Property2 = true; but using dynamic name;
   }
}
```

i should say, that i know that those properties exists in Caller class, i do not know how to set up their name dynamicly if i do not know its class caller name.
Also i should say that all this methods, property and classes are static.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't do this. |
your classes should not be static.if they have the same meothds/properties they should inherit from the same interface.

if you really insist you can use reflection [Set object property using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection)

Comment: How is the first paragraph relevant? The OP is trying to use reflection to set the value of static properties in a certain class. What makes you think there are identical methods/properties?

Comment: @Asad his question is not clear enough. but I have a feeling he is doing something wrong. trying to do something that can be solved by a common interface in a weird way.