# Using Reflection to update existing Instance

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a Dictionary this contains value pairs that I want to match and update in an instance of a class I have.

So for example I have;

```
name -> test
userid -> 1
```

In my Class I then have

```
MyClass.Name
MyClass.UserId
```

I would like to set the `MyClass.Name = test`, etc

Currently I have the method below;

```
 public static GridFilters ParseGridFilters(Dictionary<string,string> data, MyClass myClass)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in data)
            {
                Type t = typeof(MyClass);
                t.GetProperty(kvp.Value, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            }

            return myClass;
        }
```

How do I then check if the kvp.Key is in (regardless of case which I think i've covered with the BindingFlags) and then set the kvp.Value to the myClass.(kvp.Key)

Comment: What `kvp.Key is in` means? When it's in? When it's out?

Comment: [PropertyInfo.SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: TL;DR. Are you looking for "C# set property with reflection" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection

Comment: I can assume that you want to assign values from dictionary to object's properties matching properties names to dictionary keys. But your dictionary contains only string values. How `MyClass` look like? What types of properties it has?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes perfect didnt find this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the reference to the property you are retrieving with reflection, then use **SetValue** to set its value.

There's also an error in your code.
From your explanation it seems like the name of the property is in the **Key**, not the **Value**

```
 public static GridFilters ParseGridFilters(Dictionary<string,string> data, MyClass myClass)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in data)
        {
            Type t = typeof(MyClass);
            var prop = t.GetProperty(kvp.Key, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            prop.SetValue(myClass, kvp.Value, null);
        }

        return myClass;
    }
```

Comment: Thansk for this, sorry I realized my mistake with the .Value when eviewing my code.