# UWP How to Reference a Variable from another Class by string

Tags: c#, windows-8.1-universal

I have a bool named "AbsSet" in my class Section1 and I want to set it's value from another class by referencing the variable using a string. I have read through similar questions, which leads to using the GetProperty() function. However because this is a UWP, that function is not a part of the system library. Is there another way of setting this variables value by looking it up by string?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection)!

Comment: There isn't a call to InvokeMember() in System.Reflection.

Comment: Did you try [the second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/619788/1663383)?

Comment: GetProperty() is not in the library either. This is a Universal Windows app, so the library is different from the regular system library.