# Shared base for both ToolStripMenuItem and Control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

`ToolStripMenuItem` and the base type `Control` both contain the property `Enabled`.

I need to pass both types to a function such as `EnableItems(multipleItems);`, but I am not able to find a common base that contain the `Enabled` property.

`Label` or `LinkLabel` inherit from `Control` (which are typically the types I want to switch from "not enabled" to "enabled").

Is there any way to do this with out of the box features in c#?

Comment: If your runtime does not support dynamic, it is syntax sugar for reflection
See this question, how to set property by name (or get exception :-) ), using reflection  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection

Answer (score 2):

Use dynamic type. It allows you to make the compiler trust you. It can give runtime exeptions if you misuse it, but if you are careful there is no problem.

```
    public static  void Enable(List<object> ctrs, bool enable)
    {
        foreach (var ctr in ctrs)
        {
            dynamic a=ctr;
            a.Enabled = enable;
        }
    }
```

Pass it a llist with whatever you want to enable or disble. If it have no enable property it will crash at runtime, so be carefull

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't want to use a dynamic type then both [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ToolStripMenuItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem(v=vs.110).aspx) inherit from the base class [System.ComponentModel.Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx).  So you could use this as your list type:

```
public void EnableItems(IList<Component> cpnts)
{
    foreach (Component cpnt in cpnts)
    {
        ToolStripItem tsItem = cpnt as ToolStripItem;
        if (tsItem != null) { tsItem.Enabled = true; break; }

        Control ctrl = cpnt as Control;
        if (ctrl != null) { ctrl.Enabled = true; break; }
    }
}
```

You can now choose if you want the foreach loop to crash at run time (by adding an exception throw for an unexpected type) or you can choose to ignore the unexpected types.