# Dynamic Model Properties, get model property by name

Tags: c#, asp.net

Not sure how to word this...

I have a Model, here is a section of it:

```
public class AnswerSheet
    {

public string Q1 { get; set; }
public string Q2 { get; set; }
public string Q3 { get; set; }
public string Q4 { get; set; }
```

I am using a Viewmodel to reuse the same view to answer each question separately.  It is almost working.  Is there any way I can use my controller as follows to dynamically assign the model.q#, ex:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CreateNextQ([Bind(Include = "ID, qCounter, Question,Comment")] AnswerSheetCreateVM answerVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string questionAns = answerVM.Question + answerVM.Comment;
                AnswerSheet answer= db.AnswerSheets.Find(answerVM.ID);


//THIS PART HERE IS WHERE I HAVE A PROBLEM
                answer.Q(answerVM.qCounter) = questionAns;
//That one line above
                db.AnswerSheets.Add(answer);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

**So basically can I get data from my controller variable (qCounter in this case) and assign it to my model like Model.Q(qcounter)**

As a side note I am open to suggestion on how to word this question or what tags to assign to it.

Comment: It sounds like your model for `AnswerSheet` should really have a `List<string> Questions { get; set; }`

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Jon Skeet, the thing is, I want my data going back into a database of AnswerSheets where each record has colums for each question (Q1, Q2, Q3, etc).  Is there still a way I could bind my model to a list but have the data save this way in the database?  I'm using EF6 code first.

Comment: I will use a list and see how it goes into the database, apologies I should have done that before I asked the above comment.

Comment: I'm stuck on how to do this with EF6 Code first....will post if I find a way that dosn involve writing a new controller action for each question (Q1, Q2, Q3) where the integer is the only thing that changes....

Comment: It looks like I could do this with Reflection from what I have been reading but I think this will degrade performance too much...just going with the classic method

Answer (score 0):

I found this post useful:

[Set object property using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection)

This is what I ended up doing, still have to test performance:

```
string test = string.Format("Q" + answerVM.qCounter);                    
                string questionAns = (answerVM.Question + " - " + answerVM.NoComment);

                AnswerSheet answer= db.AnswerSheets.Find(answerVM.ID);
                if (answer== null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }                
                answer.GetType().GetProperty(test).SetValue(answer, questionAns, null);
db.Entry(answer).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Maybe that will help someone down the line....NOt sure if this counts as using reflection....