# Class Initialization Loop

Tags: c#, loops

The following **code:**

```
public IEnumerable<AccountStructModel> Query(string query)
{
    List<AccountStructModel> output = new List<AccountStructModel>();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Connection = connection;

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < reader.FieldCount; x++)
                {
                    output.Add(new AccountStructModel { Username = reader[1].ToString(), Password = reader[2].ToString() });
                }
            }

            command.Dispose();
        }

        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }

    return output;
}
```

Gives the following **output:**

```
Username | Password
---------|---------
  Tim    | randomPassword
```

**The problem starts here:**

```
new AccountStructModel { Username = reader[1].ToString(), Password = reader[2].ToString() }
```

I don't seem to be able to find a way to implement a loop that would take care of the following: `reader[i]` instead of `reader[1]`, `reader[2]`, `reader[3]`, `reader[4]`, maybe the answer is obvious but I don't seem to be able to find it that easily.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Does this code work? If so, then what do you want us to help with? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: Do you want a loop that gives the properties their values? If so, you can do this using [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection), but I wouldn't recommend it. That line looks fine as it is.

Comment: It is not quite clear why you seem to want to iterate over all columns of one record or simply access specific columns by index. To me it looks like you just need to throw out the inner for-loop.

Comment: Why not accessing the reader columns by name? like redaer["username"] ?

Comment: reader[0] is a record, reader[1] is the next record in the field and instead of writing reader[ + the number of the record ] can I just make a loop that would take care of that?

Comment: Wait? reader["username"] ? Let me try this

Comment: `reader[0]` is not a record, it's a field of the current record that `reader` is pointing to.

Comment: Use a SQLDataAdapter instead of SQLDataReader.  The SQLDataAdapter will automatically file a DataTable so you do not need to use a loop.  Then you can use linq to read table into a class.  Usually I find a DataTable can eliminate the need for a class.

Comment: It doesn't take string as an argument, it returns "out of range" exception

Comment: Okay I'll try DataAdapter

Comment: You are adding a User for each _colum_ (not row) that you find. Doesn't look logical.

Comment: Yea I just noticed, also reader["account-username"] actually worked, I wrote "username" instead of "account-username" that's why gave me an error

Comment: Anyway thanks I think I solved my issue

Comment: @Dan take a look at Dapper.Net. It will reduce a lot the code you wrote.