# Issue with mapping generic list of values

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I Need to map a generic key value list to my model class.

Below is the `KeyValues` class.

```
public class KeyValues
{
    public string Key   { get; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Getting this as input in `IList<KeyValues>` with below values

```
Key = "SystemId"
Value = "12"

Key = "SystemName"
Value = "LTPVBN21"

Key = "Location"
Value = "NJ2"
```

I want to map this to my below `SystemInformation` class properties. Based on Key need to set value in corresponding property.

```
public class SystemInformation
{
    public string SystemId   { get; set; }
    public string SystemName { get; set; }
    public string Location   { get; set; }
}
```

Right now iam looping the `IList<KeyValues`> object and setting the values in model comparing the key.

Is there any other way i can achieve this using Automapper or any other option since i have to do this similar operation for multiple models.

Comment: You can use reflection if what you need is more generic solution

Comment: Maybe [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/619778/2590375) ?

Comment: Check [the docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection here for this and it would be something like following:

```
SystemInformation information = new SystemInformation();
foreach(var item in values)
{
    information.GetType()
                    .GetProperty(item.Key)
                    .SetValue(information, item.Value);
}
```

See the working [DEMO Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YOEVGG).

I am using specifically **SystemInformation** object but it could be anything and you could call `GetType()` to get the type details and then further proceed by calling reflection methods.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<KeyValues> kv = new List<KeyValues>();
            kv.Add(new KeyValues() { Key = "SystemId", Value = "12" });
            kv.Add(new KeyValues() { Key = "SystemName", Value = "LTPVBN21" });
            kv.Add(new KeyValues() { Key = "Location", Value = "NJ2" });

            SystemInformation si = new SystemInformation();

            foreach (KeyValues k in kv)
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = typeof(SystemInformation).GetProperty(k.Key);

                pi.SetValue(si, k.Value);
            }

    }


    public class KeyValues
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class SystemInformation
    {
        public string SystemId { get; set; }

        public string SystemName { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Dont get the dv on this answer. its perfectly valid

Comment: No difference, helping Das out with working example. Copied it and did not see your answer yet

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I didnt downvote you (In fact I upvoted to cancel it out), and there is no need for me to answer, this is a perfectly good one - as is the other similar one.