# How can I iterate through an Entity Framework Table or Type that holds columns you normally dot into?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

So I'm using Entity Framework 6 and what I want to do is simply loop through the columns inside the model below instead of manually dotting into each column to set a value. I've tried googling a solution but I can't find one that does what I want. I get an error that the Type doesn't have a GetEnumerator() available. I have no idea how to proceed but don't want to give up without first asking. Any advice would be great, thank you everyone.

```
CaseManagementExtractedEntity addRecord = new CaseManagementExtractedEntity();
                                 

                foreach(var item in addRecord)
                {
                  item = someValue;
                }

context.CaseManagementExtractedEntity.Add(addRecord);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then you have to use `reflection` to
get all the properties of `addRecord` like this:

```
var listOfProps = addRecord.GetType().GetProperties();
```

then loop through this list and assign the value you want to each property using the `SetValue()` method.

[Look here for more info on how to set the property values with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection)