# C# set an object property value using the property name

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a C# class like this:

```
Class Test {
    public string myProp;

    public Test() {
    }
}

//(...)

Test testObject = new Test();
```

I need to get a reference to that property and set it, in that kind a way:

```
testObject.GetProperty("myProp") = (...)
```

I Can't use `PropertyInfo.SetValue` (and of course in my case I can't do `testObject.myProp = (...)`, I really need to access it that way and be able to set it with the '=' sign. Is it possible?

Comment: This already has an answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/set-object-property-using-reflection

Comment: `public string myProp;` is *not a property* - it is a field; have you tried `.GetField("myProp").SetValue(...)` ?

Comment: "I Can't use PropertyInfo.SetValue" - why not? It's really unclear where your requirements are coming from. It sounds like you're really going to be fighting C#...

Comment: There is really no way to set property (or filed as shown in the question) by name without using reflection. As @JonSkeet asked it is not clear why you have to avoid SetValue call and hence no way to suggest how to solve *your problem*. As result in general this is duplicate of using reflection - definitely can be re-opened (and possibly answered) if you decide to [edit] the post to clarify you actual goal (i.e. "need to build an expression for LINQ-to-SQL query").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, it isn't clear *why* you can't use reflection here, but: "FastMember" (via nuget) offers an API to do this reasonably efficiently (via some ref-emit at runtime, rather than simply wrapping reflection):

```cs
var obj = new Test();
var acc = FastMember.ObjectAccessor.Create(obj);
acc["myProp"] = "boo";
Console.WriteLine(obj.myProp); // "boo" i.e. it worked
```

but honestly, simple reflection is fine here too:

```cs
var obj = new Test();
obj.GetType().GetField("myProp").SetValue(obj, "boo");
Console.WriteLine(obj.myProp); // "boo" i.e. it worked
```

or even better: think about *other ways of achieving this*; the number of times you need to access a member by *a name not known at compile-time* is incredibly rare.

Comment: @MatJ I don't find it entirely impossible that they only know the name; that's ... unusual, but not impossible

Comment: Marc BTW can you please take a quick pick at recent `FastMember` PR and related discussion =)

Comment: Thanks Marc, that's perfect!
Concerning the why, it is because I'm not directly dealing with an instance of the class, but with an instance of an interface it implements.